# Вывод на экран треугольника

Tags: java

Написал код для вывода треугольника:

```
int n = key.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Результат:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * *
```

Как вывести этот треугольник в обратном порядке:

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

Answer (score 4):

нужно просто добавить немного пробелов.

```
int n = key.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n-i; j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
String text = "*";
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        System.out
                  .printf(
                      "%1$10s\n", 
                       String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, text)));
```

Паттерн `%1$10s\n` обозначает, выравнивание слева пробелами, для текста максимальной длины 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
          for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
              for (int j = 1; j <= 5 - i; j++) {
                  System.out.print(" ");
              }
              for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                  System.out.print(".");
              }
              System.out.println();
          }
          System.out.println(); 
          }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]