# Как вывести в двух циклах for треугольник?

Tags: java, for

```
public static int[][] rows(int count) {
        int[][] triangle = new int[count][];
//        for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++) {
//            for (int j = 0; j < triangle[i].length; j++) {
//                
//            }
//        }
// Треугольник в циклах должен создаваться так, как он создается ниже 
// с константными значениями
        if (count == 1) {
            triangle = new int[][]{{1}};
        } else if (count == 2) {
            triangle = new int[][]{{1}, {2, 3}};
        } else if (count == 3) {
            triangle = new int[][]{{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
        } else if (count == ...) {
            ...
        }
        return triangle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это достаточно популярная задачка (в той или иной вариации)

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] triangle =  new int[10][];
        // число, которое надо ввести в массив
        int num = 1;
        // заполнение
        for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++) {
            int[] triangleRow = new int[i + 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < triangleRow.length; j++) {
                triangleRow[j] = num++;
            }
            triangle[i] = triangleRow;
        }
        // вывод
        for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", triangle[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Похожий вопрос: [Вывод на экран треугольника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608358/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Похоже в Вашем случае первым создается пустой массив и дальше треугольник из 9 чисел в заявленных 10

Comment: @Dmitriy, ошибка у него в строчках с инициализацией подмассива (не i, а i+1, т.к. i это индекс, и поэтому для получения размерности подмассива нужно добавлять единицу), а также, что вытекает, в цикле for (i опять является индексом, а передать в это условие мы должны именно размерность). Поправил ответ

Comment: @Miron спасибо за внимательность!